# vite Internal server error: Failed to resolve entry for package "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet"

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

I'm trying to install leaflet version, pointing to some commit.

**package.json**:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "https://github.com/vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet#6bda39424bcb90c06a704e19022bc3f70f895fd7",
  },
}
```

When I compiling with vite, I get the following error:

```
[vite:resolve] Failed to resolve entry for package "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet".
The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json:
Failed to resolve entry for package "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet".
The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json.
```

---

**

Comment: Is this even feasible? Does such feature exist?

Comment: @kissu, I think so. Documentation confirms: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#github-urls

Comment: I get the same issue when my vite app, which is a package inside an npm workspaces setup, imports from another package within the same workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message with another package. For me it was enough to stop the vite server (Ctrl+C) and restart it.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. For me it was to delete de `node_modules` and reinstall all the packages again with `npm install`